# Autofill data from select to input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need autofill inputs when I select something in 'select'

```
public SomeModel : ISelectable
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public string Name {get;set}
   public string ShortName {get;set}
   public string Info {get;set}
}

public IEnumerable<SelectItem> CountriesSelect {get;set;}
public List<SomeModel> CountriesList {get;set;}
```

In cshtml i have

@Model **modelname**

in **modelname** i have  CountriesSelect  and  CountriesList

```
<select id="mainselect" asp-items="CountriesSelect"></select>

<input id="name" /> 
<input id="shortname" />
<input id="info" />
```

How to implement autofill from CountriesList to inputs on select change or smth like this

Comment: If I misunderstood in some place pls point it out and you may add more details on your issue. Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think use JQuery can solve your case. Just listen the onchange event and edit the dom elements.

In my index.cshtml, I import jquery and this is my testing result:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.HomeModelView
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
    <select asp-for="@Model.City.LocationId" asp-items="(@ViewData["city"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)" id="SubLocation_Id" class="form-control ">
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.City.LocationId"></span>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.city)
        {
            <option value="@item.LocationId&&@item.Title&&@item.SubLocation_Id">@item.Title</option>

        }
    </select>
    <input id="locationid" type="text" />
    <input id="title" type="text" />
    <input id="subid" type="text" />
</div>

<script>
    $("#SubLocation_Id").change(function () {
        var selectedid = $("#SubLocation_Id option:selected").val().split("&&");
        var locationid = selectedid[0];
        var title = selectedid[1];
        var subid = selectedid[2];
        $('#locationid').val(locationid);
        $('#title').val(title);
        $('#subid').val(subid);
    });
</script>
```